# Eclipse project root shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut in Eclipse to *jump to* or *select* the root element of the current project in the package explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no user friendly way to do this :(

Answer (score 1):

I tend to just use the "collapse all" button on the project explorer. If you use working sets, then you'll need to expand the relevant one to see your project, but otherwise I think that's as close as you'll get.

Comment: So to use only the keyboard it looks like: Ctrl-F7 -> choose package explorer -> Ctrl-Shift-Numpad divide. Pretty horrendous but it works :)

Comment: But if you didn't want to *collapse* your project ?

Comment: Lame that when using working sets (which is a great way to organize the explorer) that the collapse all button collapses one level too far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Do you always want to jump to the root of the project?

Just in case you just meant the parent element, that can be done with the left arrow. Press once to jump to the parent, twice to collapse it. If you want to go all the way to the root without collapsing anything try pressing the left-up arrows in quick succession.